# how to associate the tooltip of a composed chart from recharts to the Bar and not to the Line

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recharts

I am making a chart with React and recharts, which is a composed chart that contains a line and a bar both come from different data sets and I need the tooltip to be shown when I stand on the Bar but it is associated by default to the line as shown in the image.

do you have any idea how to make it associated to the bar or any other suggestions ?

thank you very much

[image]

here is the code for the composedChart

```
<ComposedChart data={resume?.data?.scores} >
    <defs>
      <linearGradient id="colorUv" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="1">
        <stop offset="5%" stopColor="#ff9300" stopOpacity={0.5} />
        <stop offset="95%" stopColor="#ff9300" stopOpacity={0} />
      </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <XAxis
      xAxisId={1}
      dataKey="seconds"
      type="number"
      domain={[0, Math.ceil((resume?.data?.total_seconds / 60) + 60)]}
      tickFormatter={(value) => `${Math.ceil(value / 60)}:00`}
    />
    <XAxis
      xAxisId={2}
      dataKey="seconds"
      type="number"
      hide={true}
      domain={[0, Math.ceil(getMaximumSeconds(selectedCategories) / 60)]}
      tickFormatter={(value) => `${Math.ceil(value / 60)}:00`}
    />
    <YAxis domain={[0, 100]} ticks={[0, 25, 50, 75, 100]}
      tickFormatter={(value) => `${value}%`}
    />
    <Legend verticalAlign="top"
      payload={[{ value: "Average Score", type: "line", id: "ID01", color: "#ff9300" }]}
    />
    <CartesianGrid stroke="#f5f5f5" />
    <Line type="monotone" dataKey="percentage" stroke="#ff9300" strokeWidth={3}
      xAxisId={1} dot={false} activeDot={false}  />
    {selectedCategories.length > 0 && (
      <Tooltip content={({ payload }) => {
        return (
          <Button
           size="small"
           >
            {title}
          </Button>
        );
      }} />
    )}
    {selectedCategories.length > 0 && (
      <Bar dataKey="percentage" data={orderedCategories} barSize={1} minPointSize={5} xAxisId={2}>
        {orderedCategories.map((entry: any, index: any) => {
          return <Cell key={`bar-cell-${index}`} />;
        })}
      </Bar>
    )}
    <Area type="monotone" dataKey="percentage" fill="url(#colorUv)" stroke="#ff9300" fillOpacity={0.8} xAxisId={1}
      activeDot={false} />
  </ComposedChart>
```